# error using a personal VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, office365

I created a sheet containing some values; it is a calendar that displays some informations for each day of the year.
for each day, I have an information given as a letter.
e.g. February, 3rd 2016 --> "M"

I also have a VBA function that computes the sum of the cells of a month equal to - say - "M".

My first try was to modify in VBA the value of the cell receiving the sum, with a VBA function; but my problem is that users could manually edit some cells of the calendar, so I would like to the sum cell to be recomputed, automatically, and now it doesn't.

here is my function, located in a module named "abc":

```
Function nombreCellulesDansEtat2() As Integer
Application.Volatile
Dim moisSub
Dim équipeSub
Dim étatSub
moisSub = 1
équipeSub = 1
étatSub = "M"

Dim ligneDépart As Integer
ligneDépart = 5 + (moisSub - 1) * 9
Dim ligneEnCours As Integer
ligneEnCours = ligneDépart + équipeSub

Dim cellule
Dim retour As Integer
For Each cellule In sh.Range("B" & ligneEnCours & ":AF" & ligneEnCours)
    retour = retour + IIf(cellule.Value = étatSub, 1, 0)
Next cellule
nombreCellulesDansEtat = retour


End Function
```

please don't focus on the team number("équipeSub" in french), it's not linked to the problem.

The cell containing the sum has this formula :

```
=nombreCellulesDansEtat2()
```

and the option of the automatic computing of formulas is enabled(I use excel 365 with windows 10)

the error is that the sum cell contains :

```
#VALUE!
```

and not the required sum.

thank you for having supported my bad english!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with the debugger when it gives you the error?

Comment: Also, you should consider changing the name of the post. Because that error means excel did try to recompute, but there was an error.

Comment: substituting sh for ActiveSheet the function evaluates to an integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems with your code.

1) `sh` is undefined which cause your code to crash and causes the `#VALUE!`.

2) The name you used for the return is wrong, which means that your function is returning nothing which evaluates to 0 for excel (0 is the default value for `Integer`).

To avoid such problem in the future, I would recommend to add [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) to the beginning of every file. That instruction will cause excel to report errors like these one.

```
Function nombreCellulesDansEtat2() As Integer
Application.Volatile
Dim moisSub
Dim équipeSub
Dim étatSub
moisSub = 1
équipeSub = 1
étatSub = "M"

Dim ligneDépart As Integer
ligneDépart = 5 + (moisSub - 1) * 9
Dim ligneEnCours As Integer
ligneEnCours = ligneDépart + équipeSub

Dim cellule
Dim retour As Integer
'sh is undefined. which means .Range() is called on Nothing
For Each cellule In sh.Range("B" & ligneEnCours & ":AF" & ligneEnCours)
    retour = retour + IIf(cellule.Value = étatSub, 1, 0)
Next cellule

'was nombreCellulesDansEtat
nombreCellulesDansEtat2 = retour


End Function
```

Comment: thank you, moreover I was using "sh" in my function, which no more exists as I copied this function into a new module.

Comment: @lolveley The undefined `sh` was the actual cause of the `#VALUE!` however the misstyped name would still have been a problem because the function would have always returned 0.